# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'. C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

I have a web form where a user can book a tutor. But they must first choose a course/subject, date and time for the booking. I have a method that runs through the database to check if the course,date and time do not appear in the table all in the same time. In other words, it checks if the booking made is available or someone has already booked the course for that particular date and time.

Code :

```
public void Availability(string course, string time, string date)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["tlcString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string message = "Booking already exists";
                string query = "Select * From Bookings Where [Course=@course] and [Time=@time] and [Date=@date];";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add("@course", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = course;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = time;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 50).Value = date;

                    conn.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dr.Read())
                            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);

                        dr.Close();
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            string error = "Error checking availability of booking";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + error + "');", true);
        }
    }
```

It shows this error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'

Comment: Why are you using square brackets like that in `[Course=@course]`? Don't.

Answer (score 0):

A few things

1. Fix brackets, e.g. use [time]=@time instead of [time=@time]
2. Check course, date and time for empty/null values.
3. Check if the string variable “date” will convert to a valid date.

Comment: I put up validation to make sure that all the variables cannot be null and l did a conversion already of date to short date. I guess 'll just fix the brackets